# Can OGR handle Esri's Geodatabase extensible markup language (XML) files?

Tags: convert, esri-geodatabase, ogr, xml

The USDA Forest Service [distributes](http://data.fs.usda.gov/geodata/edw/datasets.php) GIS data as Esri [Geodatabase extensible markup language](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018r00000005000000) (XML) files. I downloaded one in the hopes that I would be able to convert it to something less esoteric using OGR. However:

```
$ ogrinfo ~/Downloads/S_USA.National_Trails.xml
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `/Users/martijnv/Downloads/S_USA.National_Trails.xml' with the following drivers.
```

Unfortunately, neither the [FileGDB](http://www.gdal.org/drv_filegdb.html) driver nor the [OpenFileGDB](http://www.gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html) driver's pages explicitly mention this XML format. It seems to be defined [here on ESRI's website](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/whitepapers/view/productid/43/metaid/695).

Any way to read / convert this with FOSS4G tools?

Comment: I don't think so, can't see that format in the [ogr format list](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html). Perhaps ask on the gdal-dev mailing list.

Comment: It's weird because it's supposedly 'Esri's open mechanism for information interchange between geodatabases and other external systems' ([reference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018r00000005000000)).. You'd think they would supply a GDAL driver to back that claim up.

Comment: @mvexel. :)  http://xkcd.com/927/

Answer (score 1):

As @Luke mention in his comment:

> I don't think so, can't see that format in the [ogr format list](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html).

If you're looking for a FOSS tool to help you convert this data, you should probable look at something like [HALE](http://community.esdi-humboldt.eu/projects/hale/wiki) or [GeoKettle](http://www.spatialytics.org/projects/geokettle/)